# surround 5.1 over optical cable

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, optical

I've been looking in so many forums and tried so many troubleshooting that I am already lost. I've tried doing the steps in this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DigitalAC-3Pulseaudio and pulse audio got to show me digital output 5.1 but my rear speakers didn't make any sound, so I've tried a few troubleshooting steps in many different websites including this one. And after a few reinstalls of various software and codecs and libraries it doesn't show it anymore. So I am hoping to find a solution with you and hopfully get a response and if I am luky a solution. I will send any information that I can so for now I will let you my setup:

motherboard: asus tuf gaming b450m-plus ii

cpu: ryzen 2600

graphics card: nvidia ge force gtx 1080

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

let me know if i can give you any more information. I am really comfortable with my OS the way it is now and it took me a lot of time to set up all the things the way I like it. I don't wanna make a windows install because of something that may be just a few command lines. thank you

Comment: If you are trying to get true 5.1, it is impossible over optical cable. It doesn't support that many channels. The only way you can get 5.1 is through an encoded stream like DTS or DolbyDigital.  In this case your media must support this encoding and your audio equipment must be able to decode it.

Comment: [this is my pulse audio setup](https://i.imgur.com/9uJkNjY.png)

And my home theater is a sony DAV-DZ77T wich suport DTS. At some point I was able to select digital 5.1 but rear speakers didn't work

Comment: Have you manage to find a solution to this problem ? In fact I have the same issue, I can see the surrond option in pavucontrol, but no sound through the gnome test. Some sound are playing, but it's like more a noise thant something else.
Have a nice day

Comment: In a previous version I followed the information in this link https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2381055 and it worked perfectly, but in version 22.04 it doesn't work, the 5.1 option appears in pavucontrol, but when selecting the audio it crashes, and when it does not lock, when clicking on the speakers to test, no sound is emitted. Does anyone have the solution? Realtek ALC889 chip, spidf output.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps [here](https://blogs.gentoo.org/mgorny/2021/07/25/getting-dts-5-1-sound-via-s-pdif-or-hdmi-using-pulseaudio/), and this got me to the point where PulseAudio shows me the option of Digital 5.1 once again:

[image]

But although the Gnome sound configuration shows me 5.1:

[image]

It neither makes a sound when I want to test it by clicking the speakers icons nor any sound when I test them in the terminal.