# Surround on Ubuntu 22.04 over optical cable using ASUS Xonar SE

Tags: pulseaudio, optical

I bought a Xonar SE card so that I could utilize the DAC on my old amplifier, rather than using the crap DAC on my computer sound card.

The card is recognized by pulseaudio by default, and I can choose to output to a number of analog surround configuration. There is only on digital output, however, called `Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Xonar SoundCard` which will send stereo signals through the optical/TOSLINK cable.

There is **no setting**, however, for surround over optical. Other threads, like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357261/surround-5-1-over-optical-cable), show an entry for digital 5.1 surround.

`aplay -l` gives an entry like this:

```
ec958:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=0
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
```

Is this sort of thing supposed to work, or am I missing something?

Some folks have mentioned in comments on other threads that S/PDIF is not supposed to work with more than 2 channels, and that anything else is compressed, but I was under the impression that many movies come with the audio compressed in a format that can be sent over S/PDIF.